# Determine which element is first and do this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set focus on the first form element or class of ".focus"; whichever is visible or first.

This does not seem to sort through each to determine which comes first?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/tdvHJ/1/

```
$('.focus:visible:first, body:not(:has(.focus:visible)) input:visible:first, body:not(:has(.focus:visible)) textarea:visible:first').focus();
```

Comment: None of the elements in your fiddle have a class of focus.

Comment: the longest jQuery selector ever!

Comment: it used to be longer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will locate all visible input elements, textarea elements and .focus elements:

```
$('input:visible, .focus:visible, textarea:visible')
```

It will also have them ordered according to their order in the DOM, so the first of those elements in the document will be the first in the jQuery object. To access the first:

```
$('input:visible, .focus:visible, textarea:visible').eq(0);
```

and to focus on it:

```
$('input:visible, .focus:visible, textarea:visible').eq(0).focus();
```

Note that, as I just found out, jQuery considers elements to be 'visible' if they take up space in the document. So elements with `visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0` will still be considered visible:

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: And just a tip for the OP, if there's any way to constrain the search, that would improve performance of the selector, if slowness is observed. Something like `$(#container_with_inputs).find(...)`, for example.

Comment: the :visible was my first choice but since the other parts of the form are in ajax tabs, they are "display:none" so the visibility will not work.

Comment: @simple I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. `:visible` will exclude elements with `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
$('.focus:visible:first, body:not(:has(.focus:visible)) input:visible:first, body:not(:has(.focus:visible)) textarea:visible:first').eq(0).focus();
```

Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/tdvHJ/1/

Eq(0) select the first element... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.focus:visible:first').filter(":input").focus();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tdvHJ/3/)**

Comment: that is same result I already have. it focuses on the second input when the textarea is first. i need it to focus on the first element, input or textarea.

Comment: Look at the fiddle. Does the textarea have the class ".focus"? Add it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you are trying to achieve as there isnt any elements with the class focus.  Simply add the class focus to your input element and then us

```
$('.focus').focus();
```